# How can I change the types of my JSON response?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that has parameters that each take:

```
export interface ChangeRequest<T> {
   readonly value: T;
   readonly reason: string;
}

export async function updateJob(
   id: UUID,
   p1?: ChangeRequest<string>,
   p2?: ChangeRequest<string>
)
```

Currently I am getting a typescript error because my object has:

```
let changes = {
  "p1" : {"value":"asdf", "reason":"abc"},
  "p2" : {"value":"earth", "reason":"abc123"},
}
```

The issue is in my `changes` value, the `reason` property is nullable.

```
updateJob(id,
  changes.p1,
  changes.p2);
```

So the error is:

> argument of type `{readonly value: string;} | undefined is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChangeRequest<string> | undefined`.

Is there a wrapper function I can make that will change the `reason?` into a `reason` i.e. not nullable ?

Comment: This is a bit hard to follow, could you post an example [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) showing your example usage and error?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error message: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQAtMkBzYAJWAEcBXYAZxgB4AVAPjgG8AoOfqMEwATCEgA2ATzgA3TOPoAuOKwDcfAUNETpgzAzHKmUZKXUBfHjxiSweAKr2AkgBE4AXjjHT6nqEiwcPqSSNhw6LShMAhicLRgwpioAFIQAEYAFBqIwsqOrgA02WAAjAD8ykQk5FR0jCzeZOxF-HBgAEwVBMRklDT0TMyNpOw8AJTcljziwPDYPeQMHtwaAESlq3DKXKtyCsCriqv6wuirBXCregZIh8dp2KvmLZcdm9u78vR3QrCE55drmI7pgHiV2gBmJ5FKbYMRMHLLVardTxRIpdIZBDCF7zaqMAB0pVxC0JHTG6iAA

Comment: Only when I remove one property: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQAtMkBzYAJWAEcBXYAZxgB4AVAPjgG8AoOfqMEwATCEgA2ATzgA3TOPoAuOKwDcfAUNETpgzAzHKmUZKXUBfHjxiSweAKr2AkgBE4AXjjHT6nqEiwcPqSSNhw6LShMAhicLRgwpioAFIQAEYAFBqIwsqOrgA02WAAjAD8ykQk5FR0jCzeZOxF-HBgAEwVBMRklDT0TMyNpOw8AJTcljziwPDYPeQMHtwaAESlq3DKXKtyCsCriqv6wuir5i1w6+2b27vy9IerQrCEqwVXegZIT5hp2CV2gBmc5FKbYMRMHLLVardTxRIpdIZBDCS7zaqMAB0pXRC2xHTG6iAA

Comment: You should also post the complete error message, not only the first part.

Comment: @jabaa remove one of the "reason" properties in the changes variable - this will make it nullable.  then you will see the error.

Comment: Could you provide an [mcve] as code in your question? If a property is missing, TypeScript should break with an error. That's the whole meaning of a type system.

Comment: "The issue is in my changes value, the reason property is nullable" that doesn't show in the code you posted, but if that's the case you will need to do the null check "Is there a wrapper function I can make that will change the reason? into a reason" [yes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), the question is what do you want to do with data values missing that property? Throw an error? Filter it out of the JSON? Add a dummy default string?

Comment: @JaredSmith just filter it out if it missing

Comment: If you filter the wrong elements out, you have correct data and no problem with TypeScript. But your question doesn't contain a filter.

Answer (score 1):

You should make reason optional. `reason?`

```js
interface ChangeRequest<T> {
   readonly value: T;
   readonly reason?: string;
}

async function updateJob(
   id: string,
   p1?: ChangeRequest<string>,
   p2?: ChangeRequest<string>
) {}

let changes = {
  "p1" : {"value":"asdf", "reason":"abc"},
  "p2" : {"value":"earth"},
}
const main = async () => {
  await updateJob('17fdaf14-deb0-4b35-b2e5-94008bf52f23',
    changes.p1,
    changes.p2);
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs4gOYQEoQCOArhAM5gA8AKgHzIDeAUMq1BHACYD2IANgE9kANzh9SALmTUA3CzYce-IezhleAfikUoobHIC+TJmoEgEyGMXNhgvZMQAOnOJABS3AEYAKecmCc2mC6OAA0fo4AjFpomDj4RKQUlDp6tOGsyI4ATDEYWLgEJORUqTi0TACUjEZMfBBgyAhxuGTIALyM8gBEUd3IUgzdouIQ3RLdapww3aHI3arqIOOTngjdBhnzOf2Dw2KkKxxQYOgb4UYIvBTIALZwoB3IpubI3tXt9MyscADuD40nC53F5vABySIAdhgLhgkQALABaTgQTwABkR8M8AGYAKyIzzZCD4gCc8LRaIAHJ4YLjsjBstiwVtWM0CuQAHRRFlNFqcnKVQxMIA) is a working playground.

Comment: I don't want to make reason optional in my type, I want to fix the data or filter out the values if they are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a type guard to ensure that the data matches the schema of the type:

```
function isChangeRequest(x: unknown): x is ChangeRequest<unknown> {
   // NOTE, not really possible to determine that the value of x.value if T For
   // arbitrary T, but we can at least make sure it has the *shape*. You will
   // still have to validate the type of x.value separately
   return Boolean(x && typeof x === 'object' && 'value' in x && 'reason' in x)
}
```

Then it's pretty simple to convince the compiler:

```
if (isChangeRequest(changes.p1) && isChangeRequest(changes.p2)) {
  updateJob(
    id,
    changes.p1,
    changes.p2, // no error anymore
   );
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQAtMkBzYAJWAEcBXYAZxgB4AVAPjgG8AoOfqMEwATCEgA2ATzgA3TOPoAuOKwDcfAUNETpgzAzHKmUZKXUBfHjxiSweAKr2AkgBE4AXjjHT6nqEiwcPqSSNhw6LShMAhicLRgwpioAFIQAEYAFBqIwsqOrgA02WAAjAD8ykQk5FR0jCzeZOxF-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)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the data use the function `filterData`. If you want to fix the data use the function `fixData`

```js
interface ChangeRequest<T> {
  readonly value: T;
  readonly reason: string;
}

type UUID = string;

async function updateJob(
  id: UUID,
  p1?: ChangeRequest<string>,
  p2?: ChangeRequest<string>
) {}

const filterData = (data: { [index: string]: any }) => {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((accumulator, key) => {
    if (data[key] && data[key].reason) {
      accumulator[key] = data[key];
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, {} as { [index: string]: any });
};

const fixData = (data: { [index: string]: any }) => {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((accumulator, key) => {
    if (data[key] && !data[key].reason) {
      accumulator[key] = data[key];
      accumulator[key].reason = "";
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, {} as { [index: string]: any });
};

const main = async () => {
  const parsedData: { [index: string]: any } = {
    p1: { value: "asdf", reason: "abc" },
    p2: { value: "earth" },
  };

  let changes = filterData(parsedData);
  changes = fixData(parsedData);

  console.log(changes);

  await updateJob(
    "17fdaf14-deb0-4b35-b2e5-94008bf52f23",
    changes.p1,
    changes.p2
  );
};
main();
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs4gOYQEoQCOArhAM5gA8AKgHzIDeAUMslBHACYD2IANgE9kANzh9SALmTUA3CzYce-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-byHorisHwEBbgg9S4GQUzGiM0BHjEO57geR66huGHkNhJr4YR+6Hv8SHIHO3AoW8fDcNgMTofk5CkfIcAAO6LluwSzBAkSxHmjYZAA7DAoQwBkAAsAC0axRAADMpilRAAzAArMpURVBABkAJyKep6kABxRDAelVDAVQ6Z+eZcQ0ZBvJkFSMm5mGeVU8ikYhTALqAMSkUAA) is a working playground.